# new Status in bugzilla not showing up

Tags: bugzilla

I wanted to add a new Status
I went to Administration->Field Values->Status

I then added a new one "WAITING-REPONSE" sortkey 50

But when i go back to an existing bug that status is not there?

Is there something else i need to do?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

you must include it in the workflow:

Administration > Bug Status Workflow

Answer (score 2):

We can add new statuses in Bugzilla by adding new entries in "bug_status" table in techzilla database.

For eg:-

```
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
| id | value       | sortkey | isactive |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
|  1 | UNCONFIRMED |     100 |        1 |
|  2 | NEW         |     200 |        1 |
|  3 | ASSIGNED    |     300 |        1 |
|  4 | REOPENED    |     400 |        1 |
|  5 | RESOLVED    |     500 |        1 |
|  6 | VERIFIED    |     600 |        1 |
|  7 | CLOSED      |     700 |        1 |
|  8 | RESPONDED   |     800 |        1 |
+----+-------------+---------+----------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Add new statuses into this table using the insert query .

INSERT INTO bug_status VALUES('',.......);

- Create new bug and test in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps:-

1)First Add bug status under "Field Values" with help of Administration role.

2)Go to "Bug status workflow" and select all the check box for the row Reopen.

3)Now select check box from column Reopen "verified to Reopen"